# Solving three linear equations precision problem

Tags: equation-solving

I am solving three linear equations and the precision of one of them is not the desired one.
To be exact after finding the solutions, when i try to get the numerical value of each equation at the specific point of the solution, which should be zero, i get numbers around 10^-11 from two of the equations but the third one gives something like 10^-4.
Is the a possible solution or am i doing something wrong.
Here is the code
(I manually solved first equation Dsonic to ε0 in this code)

```
Clear["Global`*"]
q0 = 100;
q1 = 3000;
ψ0 = 1/50;     
Γ = 4/3;
μ = 1/1000;
l = μ/2;
L1 = 2000;
Ω0 = 500;
R = 0.8;
Δ0 = 4;
ε1 = 1.104959793221891`*^7;

h0[R] := Sqrt[1 - (R* μ)/(l^2 + R^2)];
ω0[R] := ( l R μ)/((l^2 + R^2)^2) ;
sM0[R] := Δ0 + q0 Δ0^(2 - Γ);
dlapr0[R] := ((-l^2 + R^2) μ)/(
2 (l^2 + R^2)^2  Sqrt[1 - (R* μ)/(l^2 + R^2)]);
Dsonic[R] := (-(-1 + Γ) ε0^2 + (-2 + Γ) ε0^2 (q0 Δ0^(1 - Γ) + 1) + 
h0[R]^2 (q0 Δ0^(1 - Γ) + 1)^3);
ε0 = Sqrt[(-(1 + q0 Δ0^(1 - Γ))^3 (1 - (R* μ)/(l^2 + R^2)))/(
1 - Γ + (-2 + Γ) (1 + q0 Δ0^(1 - Γ)))];
ndΔ0[R] := ( (q0 Δ0 + 
   Δ0^Γ) (ε0^2 (-2 R^2 + (l^2 + R^2) F) Δ0^(
    2 Γ) - (-2 R^2 + (l^2 + R^2) F) h0[R]^2 (q0 Δ0 + Δ0^Γ)^2 + 
   R (l^2 + R^2) h0[R] (q0 Δ0 + Δ0^Γ)^2  dlapr0[R]))/(Δ0^(
 3 Γ - 1)*(l^2 + R^2)*R);

sd1 = First[Simplify[Solve[ ndΔ0[R] == 0, F]]]
U0[R] := (4 π ψ0 (ε0^2 - h0[R]^2 (q0 Δ0^(1 - Γ) + 1)^2))^(1/2);

nξ1[R] := -(1/16 (-1 + Γ)  q0  Δ0^(
 1 - Γ)  (q0 Δ0^(1 - Γ) + 1) ((F^2 *h0[R]^2 sM0[R] U0[R])/(
   π R^2 ψ0) - (4 q1 U0[R]^2)/(π q0 ψ0 - π q0 Γ ψ0) + (
   2 ψ1 U0[R]^2)/(
   π ψ0^2) - (16 l^2 R μ h0[R]^2 sM0[
       R] (q0 Δ0^(1 - Γ) + 1)^2)/((l^2 + R^2)^3 U0[R]) + (4 h0[
       R]^2 sM0[
       R] (L1 U0[R] + 2 ε0 (-Ω0 + ω0[R]))^2)/((h0[R]^2 - 
        sM0[R])^2 U0[
       R]) - (16 ε0 ((ε1 - L1 Ω0) h0[R]^2 + 
        1/U0[R] sM0[
          R] (2 ε0 (Ω0 - ω0[R])^2 + U0[R] (-ε1 + L1 ω0[R]))))/(h0[
       R]^2 - sM0[R]))) ;
sd2 = First[Solve[nξ1[R] == 0, ψ1]] /. sd1

sub1=nξ1[R] /. sd1 /. sd2
sub2=ndΔ0[R] /. sd1
sub3=Dsonic[R] /. sd1
```

Comment: So you mean last 3 substitute in end of code all must be zero?
this rise another question that is the equation and coding right from the first place!?
Plz provide more clear details !

Comment: Yes all last three must be zero. Equations are correct. I cannot find any coding mistake myself.

Comment: I didn't do anything in a calculator, nor any numerical calculation by hand . You misunderstood what i said.  Nevertheless,this is a system of linear equations {nξ1[R]==0, Dsonic[R]==0,ndΔ0[R]==0}. I solve this system to find the values of ε0, ψ1, F. Substituting this values to the above equations, which should be zero gives a value of nξ1[R] of 0.000160197 which is not that precise. Is there any way to improve this precision

Comment: Note that `Precision[\[CurlyEpsilon]1 = 1.104959793221891\`*^7]` evaluates to `MachinePrecision`. A machine precision value will cause any calculation that it appears in to be done with machine precision, i.e., no precision tracking or control.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid machine precision issues, use exact numbers if you can. This is OP's code with a few small modifications, see the comments:

```
solve[args___]:=Solve[args,WorkingPrecision->100];

q0 = 100;
q1 = 3000;
ψ0 = 1/50;     
Γ = 4/3;
μ = 1/1000;
l = μ/2;
L1 = 2000;
Ω0 = 500;
R = 8/10; (* exact number *)
Δ0 = 4;
ε1 = Rationalize[1.104959793221891`*^7,0];   (* exact number *)

h0[R] := Sqrt[1 - (R* μ)/(l^2 + R^2)];
ω0[R] := ( l R μ)/((l^2 + R^2)^2) ;
sM0[R] := Δ0 + q0 Δ0^(2 - Γ);
dlapr0[R] := ((-l^2 + R^2) μ)/(
2 (l^2 + R^2)^2  Sqrt[1 - (R* μ)/(l^2 + R^2)]);
Dsonic[R] := (-(-1 + Γ) ε0^2 + (-2 + Γ) ε0^2 (q0 Δ0^(1 - Γ) + 1) + 
h0[R]^2 (q0 Δ0^(1 - Γ) + 1)^3);
ε0 = Sqrt[(-(1 + q0 Δ0^(1 - Γ))^3 (1 - (R* μ)/(l^2 + R^2)))/(
1 - Γ + (-2 + Γ) (1 + q0 Δ0^(1 - Γ)))];
ndΔ0[R] := ( (q0 Δ0 + 
   Δ0^Γ) (ε0^2 (-2 R^2 + (l^2 + R^2) F) Δ0^(
    2 Γ) - (-2 R^2 + (l^2 + R^2) F) h0[R]^2 (q0 Δ0 + Δ0^Γ)^2 + 
   R (l^2 + R^2) h0[R] (q0 Δ0 + Δ0^Γ)^2  dlapr0[R]))/(Δ0^(
 3 Γ - 1)*(l^2 + R^2)*R);

sd1 = First[Simplify[solve[ ndΔ0[R] == 0, F]]]    (* solve *)
U0[R] := (4 π ψ0 (ε0^2 - h0[R]^2 (q0 Δ0^(1 - Γ) + 1)^2))^(1/2);

nξ1[R] := -(1/16 (-1 + Γ)  q0  Δ0^(
 1 - Γ)  (q0 Δ0^(1 - Γ) + 1) ((F^2 *h0[R]^2 sM0[R] U0[R])/(
   π R^2 ψ0) - (4 q1 U0[R]^2)/(π q0 ψ0 - π q0 Γ ψ0) + (
   2 ψ1 U0[R]^2)/(
   π ψ0^2) - (16 l^2 R μ h0[R]^2 sM0[
       R] (q0 Δ0^(1 - Γ) + 1)^2)/((l^2 + R^2)^3 U0[R]) + (4 h0[
       R]^2 sM0[
       R] (L1 U0[R] + 2 ε0 (-Ω0 + ω0[R]))^2)/((h0[R]^2 - 
        sM0[R])^2 U0[
       R]) - (16 ε0 ((ε1 - L1 Ω0) h0[R]^2 + 
        1/U0[R] sM0[
          R] (2 ε0 (Ω0 - ω0[R])^2 + U0[R] (-ε1 + L1 ω0[R]))))/(h0[
       R]^2 - sM0[R]))) ;
sd2 = First[solve[nξ1[R] == 0, ψ1]] /. sd1  (* solve *)

sub1=nξ1[R] /. sd1 /. sd2 // N
(* 0. *)

sub2=ndΔ0[R] /. sd1 // N
(* 0. *)

sub3=Dsonic[R] /. sd1 // N
(* 2.91038*10^-11 *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It seems to solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

To get exact results you must rationalize your input. This gives a pretty unruly result, but by using FullSimplify you may tame it.

The rationalized input is:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
q0 = 100;
q1 = 3000;
\[Psi]0 = 1/50;
\[CapitalGamma] = 4/3;
\[Mu] = 1/1000;
l = \[Mu]/2;
L1 = 2000;
\[CapitalOmega]0 = 500;
R = 8/10;
\[CapitalDelta]0 = 4;
\[CurlyEpsilon]1 = 1104959793221891/10^8;
```

This input will result in in complicated expressions, but applying FullSimplify gives you the wanted zero without any approximations.:

```
sub1 = n\[Xi]1[R] /. sd1 /. sd2  // FullSimplify 
sub2 = nd\[CapitalDelta]0[R] /. sd1 // FullSimplify 
sub3 = Dsonic[R] /. sd1 // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help